# Infinite ByteBuffer in Java

Tags: java, buffer, bytebuffer

I'm working on a program where I'm compressing a large amount on information and storing it in bytes in a buffer. I can't use `ByteBuffer` because I don't know the finall size.

What would be a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about `ByteArrayOutputStream`? Granted, it's not exactly as convenient, but it'll do what you want. When you're finished gathering bytes you can just pop out a byte array.

Comment: Makes sense to me, since Java represents compression as Input/Output streams anyway.

Comment: This method has a 2GB limit (just to clarify)

Comment: And when you call `ByteArrayOutputStream#toByteArray` stream calls `Arrays.copyOf` which can cause `OutOfMemoryError`

Answer (score 4):

You should store large amounts of information in a file, or a database, not memory. Sooner or later you will run out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache MINA [IOBuffer](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/core/buffer/IoBuffer.html) however its resizing algo is fairly expensive.

What I do is use a direct byte buffer, you don't need to know eactly how big it will be, as unused space consumes virtual memory, not heap or even main memory.  On a 64-bit machine, virtual memory is very cheap.

You know the final size won't be much larger than the orginal.